# MYSQL - SUM scans all table even when using iINDEX

Tags: mysql, sum, explain

I have an issue with SUM query which looks like this:

```
SELECT SUM(Clicks) FROM tracker USE INDEX (CampaignID) WHERE CampaignID = $CampaignID AND (Date BETWEEN '$date_from' AND '$date_to')
```

I have an index made for both CampaignID and Date.

I used EXPLAIN to analyze what this query is doing. Here is the result I'm getting.

```
[0] => 1
[1] => SIMPLE
[2] => tracker
[3] => 
[4] => ALL
[5] => CampaignID_index,Date_index
[6] => 
[7] => 
[8] => 
[9] => 167607
[10] => 5.00
[11] => Using where
```

167607 is the table row size. So it seems that query is scanning all table even though there is actually less than 100 rows for the specific query.

I tried to force using correct INDEX, but the result was the same. 
I am a beginner at MySQL.  Any have ideas on how I can improve the query speed?

EDIT:
This is my CREATE TABLE.

```
CREATE TABLE `tracker` (
  `id` bigint(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `CampaignID` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Date` date DEFAULT NULL,
  `Clicks` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `CampaignID_index` (`CampaignID`),
  KEY `Date_index` (`Date`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=169968 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

Comment: 1) Show table's CREATE TABLE (full, not simplified). 2) Your separate indexes are not applicable. Create one composite (and covering) index ```tracker (CampaignID, `Date`, Clicks)```.

Comment: CREATE TABLE `tracker` (
  `id` bigint(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `CampaignID` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Date` date DEFAULT NULL,
  `Clicks` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `CampaignID_index` (`CampaignID`),
  KEY `Date_index` (`Date`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=169968 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

This is is my CREATE TABLE.

Comment: As I have said above - you have indices by separate fields, which are not suitable for your query. Remove them (if they not needed for another queries) and add the index provided above.

Comment: Yes, this helped. Also, I realized that I had made a mistake with variables. CampaignID was set as VARCHAR, but I was searching INT.

Comment: This is not critical - MySQL has soft datatype system.